# How to redirect server to server via .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdomain

what i am trying to do is to shift my folder to another server.

URL:

Example:

1) example.com/xyz/folder1

2) example.com/xyz/folder2

Currently i have a directory named "xyz" containing the folders which i will shift to a sub domain.

1) xyz.example.com/folder1

2) xyz.example.com/folder2

I am trying to redirect the urls to my new sub domain URL. the folders will be same as shown in the above example.

Any help?

Thanks,

Comment: better to ask in serverfault.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `/xys/.htaccess` have this rule as your **very first rule**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^xyz\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://xyz.example.com/$1 [L,NE,R=302]
```

Comment: thank you, one more thing if the url is **example.com/xyz/folder1** or **example.com/xyz/folder1/whatever** what i am looking for is it should redirect to **http://xyz.example.com/folder1**

Comment: Yes that is what this rule does. Have you tested it?